Is string deserializable JSON if the key names are not predefined?
I'm not sure if this is JSON that would be parsable into an object using a JSON deserializer:
  {"reply":{"status":"OK",
    "data":{
           "PP6goL": {"id":"A","hash":"PP6goL"},
           "UDZCbh": {"id":"B","hash":"UDZCbh"}
           }  
  }}

What makes me think it isn't, is the key of the rows in the data section, which are not key names but rather the same value as the hash inside the value of the key.
Would any JSON deserializer handle this, given the key names are not predefined?
I want to have a class to deserialize it into, but I don't think it would be possible since the member names are not predictable.

This SO post might have your answer.

Yes, handling JSON with unpredictable keys is easier with a flexible dictionary. For complex cases, using a dynamic JSON object gives you more control.
